# Mysql table with extra information to columns

Tags: mysql, datatable

just wondering if there is any possibility to add extra information to each column on mysql.

What I wan't to do when creating table, adding extra checkbox or input field like

**Datatype**, **PK** & etc..

[image: Mysql column extra information]

Comment: there is a `comment` option for fields, but each of those checkboxes represents something about the field which is representable in the sql, pk = primary key, nn = not null, etc... they're not something you can simply slap on new options and have the DBMS magically understand what it means.

Comment: I know for sure, but it suppose to be additional information for my application, so I don't have to have extra table to have each column information inserted.. ;)